# Using ldapbind to Authenticate

Tags: linux, unix, ldap

I'm trying to run [ldapbind](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/idmanage.1012/b15883/syntax_datamngmnt007.htm) to authenticate to an LDAP server. From running Java code that attempts to connect via LDAP, I know that a "Connection Timeout Error" is occurring.

However, am I running this `ldapbind` correctly? Note that I have a blank "userDn" or password used to access this server.

`ldapbind -h ldap://A.B.C.com:389/dc=foo,dc=bar -D "" -w ""`

> Error: "Cannot connect to the LDAP server"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following worked for me:

`ldapbind -p 389 -h A.B.C.com -D "" -w ""`

For my hostname, `A.B.C.com`, I did not need the `ldap://` protocol specified. Note that, for this hostname, I did not need a username or password, hence the `""` entries.

Note that, after my LDAP server came back online, running the above command produced: `bind successful`.